# Como alterar o estilo da legenda no ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gráfico

Como alterar o estilo da legenda do gráfico abaixo para que apareça o tipo da linha + o simbolo correspondente ?

Segue abaixo o comando utilizado.

```
 library(ggplot2)
 library(lubridate)
 library(gridExtra)
 library(ggpubr)
 library(Cairo)
 library(cairoDevice)
 #data.frame do grafico 1
 dados <- read.table(text = 
                  "Mes    local1 captura1  local2 captura2  eixo
                  Out     36     0.02         17    0         0
                  Nov     36     0.02         17    0         0 
                  Dez     36     10         17    10         10
                  Jan     36     10         17    10         0
                   ", header = T)
 head(dados)
 levels(dados$Mes)
 dados$Mes = factor(dados$Mes, levels=c("Out", "Nov", "Dez", "Jan"))
 g_point1 <- ggplot(subset(dados, Mes %in% c("Out", "Nov")), aes(Mes)) +
 geom_line(aes(y = captura1, color = "ADULTO"), size=1,linetype=1, group = 1)+
 geom_line(aes(y = captura2, color = "LARVA"), size=1,linetype=3, group = 2)+
 geom_point(aes(y = captura1), color="red", size=4, group = 1, shape=18) +
 geom_point(aes(y = captura2), color="black", size=2, group = 2)+
 scale_x_discrete(limits = levels(dados$Mes)) +
 scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0:5), limits = c(0,5))+
 theme_grey()+
 labs(x = "Período", y = "", title = "Evolução de larvas e adultos", subtitle = "Zona 36") +
 scale_color_manual(name= "", values=c("red", "black"), 
                 guide = guide_legend(override.aes=aes(fill=group))) +
 theme(legend.position=c("right"),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
    axis.text.x=element_text(face = "bold", color = "black", size = 10),
    axis.text.y=element_text(face = "bold", color = "black",size = 13),
    panel.background =  element_rect ( fill =  NA ) ,
    panel.grid.major =  element_line ( color =  "gray89" ) ,
    panel.ontop =  F,
    axis.line = element_line(colour = "black", size = 1))
 #data.frame do grafico 2
 dados <- read.table(text = 
                  "Mes    local1 captura1  local2 captura2  eixo
                  11.10   19      0        19      46         0
                  Out     19     5          19     23         0
                  04.11   19     8         19      18         0
                  Nov     19     18         19      5         0
                  Dez     19     10         19      10        10
                  Jan     19     10         19      10        0
                   ", header = T)
 head(dados)
 levels(dados$Mes)
 dados$Mes = factor(dados$Mes, levels=c("11.10","Out", "04.11","Nov", "Dez", "Jan"))
 g_point2 <- ggplot(subset(dados, Mes %in% c("11.10","Out","04.11","Nov")), aes(Mes)) +
 geom_line(aes(y = captura1, color = "ADULTO"), size=1,linetype=1, group = 1)+
 geom_line(aes(y = captura2, color = "LARVA"), size=1,linetype=3, group = 2)+
 geom_point(aes(y = captura1), color="red", size=4, group = 1, shape=18) +
 geom_point(aes(y = captura2), color="black", size=2, group = 2)+
 scale_x_discrete(limits = levels(dados$Mes))+
 scale_y_continuous()+
 theme_grey()+
 labs(x = "Período", y = "", title = "Evolução de larvas e adultos", subtitle = "Zona 19") +
 scale_color_manual(name= "", values=c("red", "black"), 
                 guide = guide_legend(override.aes=aes(fill=group)))+
 theme(legend.position=c("right"),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
    axis.text.x=element_text(face = "bold", color = "black", size = 10),
    axis.text.y=element_text(face = "bold", color = "black",size = 13),
    panel.background =  element_rect ( fill =  NA ) ,
    panel.grid.major =  element_line ( color =  "gray89" ) ,
    panel.ontop =  F,
    axis.line = element_line(colour = "black", size = 1))
    ggarrange(g_point1 + labs(x = "Período"), g_point2 + labs(x = "Período"),
      ncol = 2, align = "v", 
      common.legend = T, legend = "right")
```

[image: exemplo]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O código da pergunta está a falhar porque não tem `color`, `shape` e `linetype` em `aes()`. O `ggplot` atribui os valores dos elementos estéticos (***aes**thetics*) consoante os valores das variáveis, o que torna tudo mais f+acil e com experiência, intuitivo.

Neste caso vou usar a base `mtcars` e mapear a variável `am` às `aes` pedidas. Depois os valores podem ser modificados com as `scale_*`.

O `theme` final serve para prolongar as linhas um pouco mais para os lados.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  mutate(am = factor(am, labels = c("manual", "automatic"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(hp, disp, colour = am, shape = am, linetype = am)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "black")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(15, 19)) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid", "dashed")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.key.width = unit(1, 'cm'))
```

---

### Edição

Aqui vai o código completo para resolver o problema da pergunta.

Este tipo de problema geralmente está relacionado à reformatação dos dados. O formato deve ser longo e os dados estão em formato largo. Veja [esta postagem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) sobre como reformatar os dados do formato largo para o longo.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

#data.frame do grafico 1
dados <- read.table(text =
"Mes    local1 captura1  local2 captura2  eixo
Out     36     0.02         17    0         0
Nov     36     0.02         17    0         0
Dez     36     10         17    10         10
Jan     36     10         17    10         0
", header = TRUE)

longo1 <- dados %>%
  select(-local2) %>%
  mutate(Mes = ordered(Mes, levels = c("Out", "Nov", "Dez", "Jan"))) %>%
  filter(Mes < "Dez") %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with("captura"),
    names_to = "captura"
  ) %>%
  mutate(captura = ifelse(captura == "captura1", "ADULTO", "LARVA"))
```

---

```
dados <- read.table(text =
"Mes    local1 captura1  local2 captura2  eixo
11.10   19      0        19      46         0
Out     19     5          19     23         0
04.11   19     8         19      18         0
Nov     19     18         19      5         0
Dez     19     10         19      10        10
Jan     19     10         19      10        0
", header = TRUE)

longo2 <- dados %>%
  select(-local2) %>%
  mutate(Mes = ordered(Mes, levels = c("11.10", "Out", "04.11", "Nov", "Dez", "Jan"))) %>%
  filter(Mes < "Dez") %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with("captura"),
    names_to = "captura"
  ) %>%
  mutate(captura = ifelse(captura == "captura1", "ADULTO", "LARVA"))
```

---

Agora os gráficos.
Em primeiro lugar vou definir um `theme` comum, para simplificar o código que se seguirá.

```
theme_larvas_adultos <- function(){
  theme_grey() +    #replace elements we want to change
    theme(
      legend.position=c("right"),
      plot.subtitle = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12),
      axis.line = element_line(colour = "black", size = 1),
      axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", colour = "black", size = 10),
      axis.text.y = element_text(face = "bold", colour = "black", size = 13),
      panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA) ,
      panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray89") ,
      panel.ontop = FALSE
    )
}
```

E traçar um gráfico de cada vez.

```
g_point1 <- ggplot(longo1, aes(Mes, value, colour = captura, group = captura)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = captura), size = 1.5) +
  geom_point(aes(size = captura, shape = captura)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 0:5, limits = c(0, 5))+
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "black")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid", "dashed")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(15, 19)) +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(4, 3)) +
  labs(x = "Período", y = "", title = "Evolução de larvas e adultos", subtitle = "Zona 36") +
  theme_larvas_adultos()

g_point2 <- ggplot(longo2, aes(Mes, value, colour = captura, group = captura)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = captura), size = 1.5) +
  geom_point(aes(size = captura, shape = captura)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "black")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid", "dashed")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(15, 19)) +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(4, 3)) +
  labs(x = "Período", y = "", title = "Evolução de larvas e adultos", subtitle = "Zona 19") +
  theme_larvas_adultos()

ggarrange(
  g_point1, g_point2,
  ncol = 2, align = "v",
  legend = "right",
  common.legend = TRUE
)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Rui poderia me ajudar a organizar o raciocinio no meu comando? estou com dificuldade de adequar `color` , `shape` e `linetype` em `aes()`.

Comment: @patrickcesar Feito, veja agora.